# is there any way to run j2me(jar/jad)program without using sun java wireless tool kit or any ide for j2me?

Tags: java-me, emulation, java-wireless-toolkit

I want to run my j2me program (jar/jad) in my PC without using any IDE or sun java wireless toolkit or something like that?

Is there any other tool provided by Oracle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah possible. You can use [Java ME SDK 3.0.5](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/overview/index.html). And lot of other SDK available for run the Java ME applications on PC.  These are [Sprint SDK](http://developer.sprint.com/site/global/develop/mobile_platforms/java_me/javame.jsp), [Samsung SDK](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?cntsId=1406&platformId=3),  [Sony Ericsson SDK](http://sony-ericsson-j2me-sdk.software.informer.com/) or [LG SDK](http://developer.lgmobile.com/lge.mdn.tnd.RetrieveDocAndTools.dev?objectType=T#1). Also you can use [Nokia RDA device](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/) for run your Java ME application.

Comment: I dont want development environment and i need only device emulator to run jar/jad files.I am not going to develop j2me application and only run the jar/jad files.Is there any tool available like that?

Comment: Yeah these are all emulators like java wireless toolkit. You can run Java ME application on these emulators. Also If you want, use it as your development. Install these in your PC and run the `ktoolbar`. `ktoolbar` having lot of emulators for testing your application.

Comment: :I understood bharath.It has also devleopment environment.So, It takes more memory than emulator only environment.That's i asked non devleopment based tool for run my jar/jad files...

Comment: Just try it then only you can understand that. I suggest sprint is better than other sdk. And this is good one also. This SDK having lot of simulators for testing purpose. Or you can choose Nokia RDA devices or [Micro emulator](http://www.microemu.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Samsung released its tool kit which is similar to "sun java wireless tool kit". Its better to try that.Many vendors like Nokia provide their SDKs.It is better that you search the net and try.They provide the development environment so that you can develop a j2me app and also be able to run jad/jar files.

But I think there is no only running environment.The tool for running environment comes with the development environment (SDKs).